# How can I turn off dark mode for Jira Confluence?

Tags: jira, confluence

I'm new to Jira Confluence. When I first created Confluence, there was a change theme (beta) button on the right, so I changed the theme to dark mode through that button.

But now I want to turn off dark mode again, but I don't know how to do it (There is no change theme button). Maybe it's because I'm a Korean user and it's translated as theme, not color scheme. Currently, Confluence has colors like the following image.

[image]

As additional information, I noticed that in the CSS of that page, I have data-color-mode="dark".

[image]

Also, when I changed the theme, there were "light" and "dark" options, just like when you change the mode in Windows, and there was also an option to follow the default Windows app mode.

How can I turn off the dark mode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The option to turn it off is on your profile picture, in the top right corner of the page.